# Custom scope for a view model with Hilt

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt

Let’s say I have a view showing a list of contacts and a second view  showing the detail of a contact. I have used @ViewModelScoped for the second view ViewModel which works fine when I navigate the first time to a contact detail view, but on every following navigation, the view shows the details of the previous contact before loading and showing the new details. Should I implement a “reset” mechanism that clears the content of the view model when navigating to a new contact, or should I use a different scope? I considered to not use any scope but then screen orientation changes would make the view model trigger the load again. What do you advice me to do ?

I'm getting the view model through `by viewModels()` if that matters. I saw there's a `by navGraphViewModels()` but I don't know if I can use that while my app uses Compose?

Ideally, a new instance of the view model should be created for each contact. That way if I navigate back to a contact page I already seen, the view model is already populated. Maybe with some sort of limit on how many instances can be created to avoid memory leak/overflow.

Comment: Is the contact details appears on a navigation route? Then you can use `val viewModel = viewModel<YourViewModelClass>()` inside composable. `viewModels()` is rarely needs to be used in Compose. May be related answers: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69491452/3585796), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69852682/3585796)

Comment: It seems like using `hiltViewModel()` did the trick, thanks for the hint!

Comment: You're welcome! If one of my answers helped you, please give it an upvote.